# Let $S=${$a^2+b^2: a,b\in\mathbb{N}$}. Prove that $S$ is closed under multiplication.

Tags: proof-writing

Let $S=${$a^2+b^2: a,b\in\mathbb{N}$}. Prove that $S$ is closed under multiplication.

Proof trying. Let $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2}$ in $\mathbb{N}$. We will show that $\left( a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}\right) \left( a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}\right) \in S$.

So,  $\left( a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}\right) \left( a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}\right)=a_{1}^{2}a_{2}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}b_{2}^{2}+a_{1}^2b_{2}^2+b_{1}^2a_{2}^2=\left( a_{1}a_{2}\right) ^{2}+\left( b_{1}b_{2}\right) ^{2}+\left( a_{1}b_{2}\right) ^{2}+\left( a_{2}b_{1}\right) ^{2}$. bla bla...

So, How can I show this in $S$?

Comment: $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$$

Comment: Let's not ignore the other solution: $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac \pm bd)^2+(ad \mp bc)^2$

Comment: I have a question that how can we say $ad-bc>0$ for saying $ad-bc\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @did May you see my last comment?

Comment: @PM2Ring May you see my last comment?

Comment: @KathySong We don't have to worry about that because we're working with squares. If $ad-bc<0$ then just use $bc-ad$. Or swap a&b and c&d.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, you are right. Thanks.